# Why does getting a single block in NEO prevent getting the remainder of the blocks?

Tags: forloop, plugin-neo

I have blocks set up for nutritional values: Calories, Total Fat, Carbohydrates, etc. These are set up in NEO blocks.

I can successfully loop through all of the NEO blocks (about 20 rows total) and output the content using this for loop:

```
{% for block in entry.nutritionBuilder.level(1).all() %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Later, I added a line ABOVE this loop to retrieve the content of a single block:

```
{% set item = entry.nutritionBuilder.type('blockCalories').one() %}
{{ item.nutritionValue }}
```

This works, in that it will output the value I need to retrieve. However, the for loop below this line now only outputs a single row from nutritionBuilder which is blockCalories row.

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oli, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Your answer was close, but there's a slight modification:

```
{% set blocks = entry.nutritionBuilder %}

{% set item = clone(blocks).type('blockCalories').one() %}
{{ item.nutrionValue }}

{% for block in clone(blocks).level(1).all() %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

The cloning needs to happen when setting the `item` variable as well as in the for loop.

Comment: Ha, too quick :) I've corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of [a change in Craft 3](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/upgrade.html#cloning-element-queries) and you need to `clone` your query ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/functions.html#clone)).

I have not tested this but the below should work:

```
{% set blocks = entry.nutritionBuilder %}

{% set item = clone(blocks).type('blockCalories').one() %}
{{ item.nutritionValue }}

{% for block in clone(blocks).level(1).all() %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```